# java.lang.ClassCastException in RecyclerView, Fragment, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I recieve the following error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.saahil.smehrashop.ProductListActivity cannot be cast to 
 com.saahil.smehrashop.ProductAdapter$ItemClicked
    at com.saahil.smehrashop.ProductAdapter.<init>(ProductAdapter.java:30)
    at com.saahil.smehrashop.HomeFragment$1.onResponse(HomeFragment.java:81)
```

The code for ProductListActivity is as follows-

```js
package com.saahil.smehrashop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

The code for HomeFragment.java is as follows-

```js
package com.saahil.smehrashop;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.saahil.smehrashop.Model.Products;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements ProductAdapter.ItemClicked {
    View root;
    RecyclerView rvProductList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter productAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Products> productList;
    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi;
    Context context;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        context=this.getActivity();

        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.29.214:8000/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        jsonPlaceHolderApi=retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        rvProductList=root.findViewById(R.id.rvProductList);
        rvProductList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        productList=new ArrayList<>();

        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        rvProductList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        
        getProducts();
    }

    private void getProducts() {
        Call<ArrayList<Products>> call=jsonPlaceHolderApi.getProducts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Products>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Products>> call, Response<ArrayList<Products>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Code: "+ response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                productList=response.body();
                productAdapter=new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), productList);
                rvProductList.setAdapter(productAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Products>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int index) {

    }
}
```

The code for ProductAdapter.java is as follow-

```js
package com.saahil.smehrashop;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.saahil.smehrashop.Model.Products;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Products> products;
    ItemClicked activity;

    public interface ItemClicked{
        void onItemClicked(int index);
    }

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Products> list){
        products=list;
        activity=(ItemClicked) context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvName, tvPrice, tvDescription;
        ImageView ivProductImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            ivProductImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProductImage);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    activity.onItemClicked(products.indexOf((Products) view.getTag()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_items, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setTag(products.get(position));
        holder.tvName.setText(products.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(products.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvPrice.setText("$"+products.get(position).getPrice());
        Picasso.get().load(products.get(position).getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).into(holder.ivProductImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }
}
```

The code for JsonPlaceHolderApi.java is as follow-

```js
package com.saahil.smehrashop;

import com.saahil.smehrashop.Model.Products;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("api/")
    Call<ArrayList<Products>>getProducts();
}
```

App started giving this error after adding Interface ItemClicked...
Android Studio shows error in logcat in this line-

```
activity=(ItemClicked) context;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity is declared as

```
public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

I.e., it does **not** implement `ItemClicked` - it is your Fragment, not your `Activity` that implements that interface. Therefore you should change your adapter to take an instance of `ItemClicked` (rather than casting internally):

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Products> products;
    ItemClicked activity;

    public interface ItemClicked{
        void onItemClicked(int index);
    }

    public ProductAdapter(ItemClicked itemClicked, ArrayList<Products> list){
        products = list;
        activity = itemClicked;
    }
```

Then change your fragment to pass itself in:

```
productAdapter=new ProductAdapter(HomeFragment.this, productList);
```